# Why validation F1, precision and recall metrics are 0 for Keras model while training values are not 0?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, data-science

I'm trying to train a neural network in order to do binary classification. The part of my code I am having trouble with is the following:

```
    # Grid search
from keras import backend as K

# Define recall, precision and f1 functions
def recall_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall
       
def precision_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

def f1_m(y_true, y_pred):
    precision = precision_m(y_true, y_pred)
    recall = recall_m(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))

def create_model(conv_layers, learning_rate, alpha_value):
  model = Sequential()
  for i in range(conv_layers):
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), strides = (1,1), kernel_regularizer=l2(0.005)))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = alpha_value))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (1,1)))
    
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  model.add(Flatten())

  model.add(Dense(32, bias_regularizer=l2(0.001), kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha_value))
  
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(1))
  model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['acc', f1_m, recall_m, precision_m])
  return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=1)

params_to_test_gen = {'epochs':[20,30,40,50,60], 'batch_size': [100,200,300], 'conv_layers':[1,2,3], 'learning_rate':[0.005,0.001,0.01], 'alpha_value':[0.001, 0.05, 0.01, 0.1]}
  
gsearch_0 = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid = params_to_test_gen, scoring='recall', n_jobs= None, iid=False, cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle = True, random_state = 0), verbose = 5)
gsearch_0.fit(x_train, y_train, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
print("Best score: ", gsearch_0.best_score_)
print("Best parameters: ", gsearch_0.best_params_)
```

after executing I get:

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 540 candidates, totalling 1620 fits
[CV] alpha_value=0.001, batch_size=100, conv_layers=1, epochs=20, learning_rate=0.005 
Epoch 1/20
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
9/9 [==============================] - 8s 684ms/step - loss: 0.3326 - acc: 0.7939 - f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - precision_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 123.8852 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_precision_m: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/20
9/9 [==============================] - 5s 506ms/step - loss: 0.0820 - acc: 1.0000 - f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - precision_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 154.7310 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_precision_m: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/20
9/9 [==============================] - 6s 729ms/step - loss: 0.0821 - acc: 1.0000 - f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - precision_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 164.7593 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_precision_m: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/20
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 486ms/step - loss: 0.0792 - acc: 1.0000 - f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - precision_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 166.9239 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_precision_m: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/20
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 488ms/step - loss: 0.0757 - acc: 1.0000 - f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - precision_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 165.2710 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_precision_m: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/20
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 488ms/step - loss: 0.0719 - acc: 1.0000 - f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - precision_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 161.8743 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_precision_m: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/20
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 487ms/step - loss: 0.0682 - acc: 1.0000 - f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - precision_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 157.7498 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall_m: 0.0000e+00 - val_precision_m: 0.0000e+00
```

and so on because it never ends. I don't understand why F1, recall and precision metrics are 0.0000e+00. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well its because your model is heavily overfitting, did you look at the validation loss?

Comment: Numerically, if your training labels are all 0 and there are no positives, you can have 100% accuracy and 0 of precision/recall/f1.